# Error with PostgreSQL as a Vector Database

Tags: python, postgresql, vector-database, pgvector

I am trying to setup a PostgreSQL as vector database by following this guide: https://www.timescale.com/blog/postgresql-as-a-vector-database-create-store-and-query-openai-embeddings-with-pgvector/

However, I am struck at this step:

```
#Batch insert embeddings and metadata from dataframe into PostgreSQL database
register_vector(conn)
cur = conn.cursor()
# Prepare the list of tuples to insert
data_list = [(row['title'], row['url'], row['content'], int(row['tokens']), np.array(row['embeddings'])) for index, row in df_new.iterrows()]
# Use execute_values to perform batch insertion
execute_values(cur, "INSERT INTO embeddings (title, url, content, tokens, embedding) VALUES %s", data_list)
# Commit after we insert all embeddings
conn.commit()
```

The error I am getting is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/vector-cookbook-main/openai_pgvector_helloworld/script.py", line 166, in <module>
    execute_values(cur, "INSERT INTO embeddings (title, url, content, tokens, embedding) VALUES %s;", data_list)
  File "~/vector-cookbook-main/openai_pgvector_helloworld/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/extras.py", line 1296, in execute_values
    parts.append(cur.mogrify(template, args))
  File "~/vector-cookbook-main/openai_pgvector_helloworld/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pgvector/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 14, in getquoted
    return adapt(to_db(self._vector)).getquoted()
  File "~/vector-cookbook-main/openai_pgvector_helloworld/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pgvector/utils/__init__.py", line 27, in to_db
    raise ValueError('expected ndim to be 1')
ValueError: expected ndim to be 1
```

This error occurs at execute_values method and I am not quite sure what that means.

I am very new to the Vector database and would appreciate any help in resolving this.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the same input data as the example? It looks like your data has multiple dimensions. For instance if your data is stored as a 2x2 matrix (eg `[[1,2],[3,4]]`) then you need to reshape it into a 1x4 vector (eg. `[1,2,3,4]`) so that it can be stored in the database. Even then, it looks like the example is expecting a vector with exactly 1,536 items (ie.  the column is `embedding vector(1536)`).

Comment: @Dunes Yes, I am using the same data provided in the example. I just confirmed the length of an embedding in the csv which is exactly 1536.